# rkhunter: "Suspicious Shared Memory segments"

Tags: linux, rkhunter

I have here a new installed server with CentOS7 and a GroupOffice installation on it. After installing rkhunter and starting a rkhunter check I get:

```
[09:58:15] Suspicious Shared Memory segments
[09:58:15]   Process:     PID: 1769    Owner: apache         [ Found ]
[09:58:15]   Suspicious Shared Memory segments               [ Warning ]
```

Anybody knows what the "Suspicious Shared Memory segments" means? How can I check if this is a false positive? And if so: How can I white list this error?

**EDIT**

If I try to list the process with the ps command the process with the PID 1769 isn't there:

```
# ps -p 1769
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
# ps aux | grep 1769
root     12777  0.0  0.0 112660   960 pts/0    S+   10:25   0:00 grep --color=auto 1769
# ps aux | grep apache
apache   12606  0.0  0.5 537092 10224 ?        S    10:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   12607  0.0  0.5 537092 10224 ?        S    10:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   12608  0.0  0.5 537092 10224 ?        S    10:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   12609  0.0  0.5 537092 10224 ?        S    10:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   12610  0.0  0.5 537092 10224 ?        S    10:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root     12779  0.0  0.0 112660   960 pts/0    S+   10:26   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

Comment: This is a question for "Information Security SE": https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/220302/find-out-if-a-process-is-allowed-to-use-shared-memory-segments

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [changelog for v 1.4.4](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=220765):

> Added the ALLOWIPCPROC configuration file option. This can be
>      used to whitelist suspicious processes using shared memory
>      segments (found during the 'ipc_shared_mem' check).

So to whitelist use the following

```
ALLOWIPCPROC=path/to/service
```

e.g.

```
ALLOWIPCPROC=/usr/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why Apache uses shared memory segments, or why it's safe to allow that. Encouraging people to blindly ignore warnings is not very helpful - even if it's safe this time around, it might not be the next time they do it.

Answer (score 12):

The concept of Shared Memory Segments is explained on: http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/shm/what-is-shm.html. As the name suggests, a Shared Memory Segment is a memory segment that can be shared by multiple processes. The Apache web server process, which is the file: **/usr/sbin/httpd** uses shared memory. It uses shared memory in order to share data across the Apache server workers. This is explained on: [Shared Object Cache in Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/socache.html)

Accessing shared memory is a security risk because it allows a process to read and potentially modify memory used by another process. Only trusted processes should be allowed to access shared memory. Rkhunter security scanning is a bit strict since it regards the trusted process **/usr/sbin/httpd** as suspicious.

This warning can be safely ignored as suggested on the Plesk forum: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001160954-What-Watchdog-warnings-can-be-safely-ignored-on-a-Plesk-server.

To ignore the warning, the path to the process that is accessing the Shared Memory Segement, should be added to **ALLOWIPCPROC** option in the rkhunter.conf configuration file. The path to the process in this case is: **/usr/sbin/httpd**.

The rkhunter.conf file contains following documentation on the **ALLOWIPCPROC** option:

> Allow the specified process pathnames to use shared memory segments.
>   This option may be specified more than once, and may use wildcard
>   characters. The default value is the null string.

Comment: Upvoting since this is better than the accepted answer, but it still doesn't explain *why* it's safe to ignore.  Why does Apache need shared memory segments?

Answer (score 0):

After stopping the httpd the warning is gone (like expected). After starting the httpd the warning is there again (with the same PID!). I had tried this several times (every case with the same result).

**But**: After rebooting the server the warning is gone. I have playing around with the server (login to GroupOffice, restarting httpd and so on) and it seems the warning is gone persistently (hopefully). However, I will observe this thing in the next days ...

I have no idea what the "Suspicious Shared Memory segments" warning means and how I can figure out if this is a false positive or not. So I will also don't mark this question/answer as "answered" ...

Thanks and regards,
Steffen

Comment: You scared them away ;)